# "ADOM XML v4" in XE4

Tags: c++, xml, c++builder

I am trying to use the "ADOM MXL v4" in me new C++ Builder XE4 application like This:

```
xmlDoc = new TXMLDocument(NULL);
xmlDoc->DOMVendor = GetDOMVendor(L"ADOM XML v4");
```

but the `GetDOMVendor(L"ADOM XML v4");` throws an exception with the message "No Matching DOM Vendor: ADOM XML v4".

Can someone please help?

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DOM implementation has to be registered with `RegisterDOMVendor()` before `GetDOMVendor()` can return it. The VCL's native `"ADOM XML v4"` implementation is the default DOM vendor only on Mac OSX platforms.  To activate it on other platforms, try adding an `#include <Xml.adomxmldom.hpp>` statement to your code.  If that does not work, you might need to use a `#pragma link "Xml.adomxmldom"` statement instead.

Comment: I already had the header included but linking the Xml.adomxmldom fixed the problem. Thank you